# formula to work percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to find a formula that will perform a specific function.

I have two values, for example 15 and 50. 15 (b6) is the number of questions I have correct and 50 (c6) is the total number of question, I would a formula that will work out the percentage of how many questions I have correct. I have a current formula that looks like: =(C6-B6)/ABS(C6) but this returns the wrong value. I suppose what I am looking for a formula which will tell me what percentage 15 is of 50.

Comment: Your formula seems correct. Attach an image.

Comment: I cannot attach an image because my rep is not above 10!

Comment: Simply post the link here and someone will edit it in

Comment: By the way you don't really need ABS on the bottom. You could put it on top but it isn't needed for your situation. I don't get how it "doesn't work".  (50-15)/50 = 35/50 = 0.70 = 70%

Comment: ok, ok right I have that formula currently in my spread sheet, I have the values of 15/54 ( 15 out of 54). However the current formula returns a value of 72.22%, but that's is not the percentage of questions that was answered correctly. I'm pretty sure this formula show the difference in percentage?

Comment: um 15 out of 54 would mean 72.22% are wrong. So your formula is still right.

Comment: (54-15)/54 = 0.72222 = 72.22%

Comment: Right! so how would I display the percentage that is right!?

Comment: I don't see how your formula is wrong at all from what you posted... The values you are posting to be wrong, are right.

Comment: yes but what I would like is for the formula to display the percentage that was answered correctly not incorrect as the 72.22% represents the amount of incorrect questions

Comment: =1-[(C6-B6)/C6]

Comment: that formula returns and error message that wants me to use '=-1*(C3-B3)*(C3)' this formula instead? and I presume this multiplies?

Comment: dont use square brackets. I just used them to illustrate to you that you are subtracting that quantity from 1

Comment: =1-((C6-B6)/C6)

Comment: I feel like Alice in Wonderland.  The comments and answer bear no relationship to the question. 1) Where did 54 come from? 2)How does the subtraction relate to anything?  15 correct out of 50 total =15/50,  =B6/C6.  Expressing it as a percentage is just formatting.

Comment: @fixer1234: Well, I guess that makes me the Cheshire Cat. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize what was in the comments section.

Kyle has two cells:

```
C6 = Total questions

B6 = Questions asked
```

Here is what he wants to find:

```
Percentage questions not asked = (C6-B6)/B6

Percentage questions asked = 1-((C6-B6)/B6)
```

Using the "1 -" will inverse the original result. 
This may seem basic to some but hopefully it helps others.

Answer (score 0):

To recap and *correct*,

> `B6` = number of questions answered correctly
>   `C6` = total questions asked

So the portion of questions answered correctly is `B6/C6`. 
For `B6` = 15 and `C6` = 50, this will evaluate to `0.3`. 
You can display this as `30%` by formatting the cell as `Percentage`,
or you can simply multiply by 100.

By the way,

[image: equation]

... so `B6/C6` is equivalent to the formula that Eric posted in a comment,
but not the one he posted in his answer.

Comment: Your answer is, of course, correct.  But this thread gives me the heebie-geebies in terms of preserving it for future reference.  I'm not sure where Kyle was headed with this or how the thread ended up so absurd (or why he thinks the accepted answer answers the question).  I doubt a future visitor to the site will have the same question (it's too basic for Super User), but if they did, this thread sure wouldn't help.  I'd recommend giving Kyle a chance to read your answer, and then putting this thread out of its misery.